# Converting repetative javascript statements to arrays in loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

I am dynamically changing the options in 8 selects based on a separate selected option.
The process handles counties in a state and updating all 8 selects for each county in a state is terribly repetitive as each option can only exist in one select.

My original code was thrown together quickly but worked fine:

```
FLCounties = [
"Alachua",
"Baker",
"Bay",
"etc."];

//Get the selects
var countyDrop1 = document.getElementById("county1");
var countyDrop2 = document.getElementById("county2");
var countyDrop3 = document.getElementById("county3");
var countyDrop4 = document.getElementById("county4");
var countyDrop5 = document.getElementById("county5");
var countyDrop6 = document.getElementById("county6");
var countyDrop7 = document.getElementById("county7");
var countyDrop8 = document.getElementById("county8");

//Get the default state if any
var initialState = document.getElementById("state").value;
getState(initialState);

//Called from onchange on the state select
function getState(sel) {

//Clear previous options and add a notice to select a state
while (countyDrop1.firstChild) {
    countyDrop1.removeChild(countyDrop1.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl1= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl1.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl1.value = "";
    countyDrop1.appendChild(defaultEl1);

while (countyDrop2.firstChild) {
    countyDrop2.removeChild(countyDrop2.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl2= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl2.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl2.value = "";
    countyDrop2.appendChild(defaultEl2);

while (countyDrop3.firstChild) {
    countyDrop3.removeChild(countyDrop3.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl3= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl3.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl3.value = "";
    countyDrop3.appendChild(defaultEl3);

while (countyDrop4.firstChild) {
    countyDrop4.removeChild(countyDrop4.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl4= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl4.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl4.value = "";
    countyDrop4.appendChild(defaultEl4);

while (countyDrop5.firstChild) {
    countyDrop5.removeChild(countyDrop5.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl5= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl5.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl5.value = "";
    countyDrop5.appendChild(defaultEl5);

while (countyDrop6.firstChild) {
    countyDrop6.removeChild(countyDrop6.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl6= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl6.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl6.value = "";
    countyDrop6.appendChild(defaultEl6);

while (countyDrop7.firstChild) {
    countyDrop7.removeChild(countyDrop7.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl7= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl7.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl7.value = "";
    countyDrop7.appendChild(defaultEl7);

while (countyDrop8.firstChild) {
    countyDrop8.removeChild(countyDrop8.firstChild);
};
    var defaultEl8= document.createElement("option");
    defaultEl8.textContent = "Select a state above first.";
    defaultEl8.value = "";
    countyDrop8.appendChild(defaultEl8);

//if no state is selected, do nothing  
if (sel != ""){
    switch (sel){
        //value of option Florida
        case "FL":
            //change "select a state first" to "select a county"
            countyDrop1.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop2.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop3.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop4.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop5.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop6.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop7.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            countyDrop8.firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
            for(var i = 0; i < FLCounties.length; i++) {

                var opt = FLCounties[i];
                var el1 = document.createElement("option");
                el1.textContent = opt;
                el1.value = opt;
                var el2 = document.createElement("option");
                el2.textContent = opt;
                el2.value = opt;
                var el3 = document.createElement("option");
                el3.textContent = opt;
                el3.value = opt;
                var el4 = document.createElement("option");
                el4.textContent = opt;
                el4.value = opt;
                var el5 = document.createElement("option");
                el5.textContent = opt;
                el5.value = opt;
                var el6 = document.createElement("option");
                el6.textContent = opt;
                el6.value = opt;
                var el7 = document.createElement("option");
                el7.textContent = opt;
                el7.value = opt;
                var el8 = document.createElement("option");
                el8.textContent = opt;
                el8.value = opt;
                countyDrop1.appendChild(el1);
                countyDrop2.appendChild(el2);
                countyDrop3.appendChild(el3);
                countyDrop4.appendChild(el4);
                countyDrop5.appendChild(el5);
                countyDrop6.appendChild(el6);
                countyDrop7.appendChild(el7);
                countyDrop8.appendChild(el8);
            }
            break;
            [rinse and repeat, 49 times]
```

I tried condensing it into a series of arrays and for loops, which really shortens the code, but it breaks the page (an infinite loop somewhere I'm sure).

New code (does not work):

```
var FLCounties = [
//same as above
];

var dropdowns = [
countyDrop1 = document.getElementById("county1"),
countyDrop2 = document.getElementById("county2"),
countyDrop3 = document.getElementById("county3"),
countyDrop4 = document.getElementById("county4"),
countyDrop5 = document.getElementById("county5"),
countyDrop6 = document.getElementById("county6"),
countyDrop7 = document.getElementById("county7"),
countyDrop8 = document.getElementById("county8")
];

var defaultOptions = [
defaultEl1 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl2 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl3 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl4 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl5 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl6 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl7 = document.createElement("option"),
defaultEl8 = document.createElement("option")
];

var options = [
el1 = document.createElement("option"),
el2 = document.createElement("option"),
el3 = document.createElement("option"),
el4 = document.createElement("option"),
el5 = document.createElement("option"),
el6 = document.createElement("option"),
el7 = document.createElement("option"),
el8 = document.createElement("option")
];

var initialState = document.getElementById("state").value;
getState(initialState);

function getState(sel) {
    //new clear list
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        while (dropdowns[i].firstChild) {
            dropdowns[i].removeChild(dropdowns[i].firstChild);
        }
        defaultOptions[i].textContent = "Select a state above first.";
        defaultOptions[i].value = "";
        dropdowns[i].appendChild(defaultOptions[i]);
    }
    if (sel != ""){
        var opt;
        switch (sel){
            case "FL":
                //new change "select a state first" to "select a county"
                for (i=0;i<8;i++){
                    dropdowns[i].firstChild.textContent = "- Select a County -";
                }
                //new create 8 unique options and add them to the selects
                for(i=0;i<FLCounties.length;i++){
                    opt = FLCounties[i];
                    for (i=0;i<8;i++){
                        options[i].textContent = opt;
                        options[i].value = opt;
                        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
                            dropdowns[i].appendChild(options[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? This should execute quicker right? Instead its holding the page from loading indefinitely.

---

---

Edit: I did find one glaring problem. The `dropdowns[i].appendChild(options[i]);` loop should not be in the loop above it. It should run after options has been set.

New snippet:

```
//new create 8 unique options and add them to the selects
for(i=0;i<FLCounties.length;i++){
    opt = FLCounties[i];
    for (i=0;i<8;i++){
        options[i].textContent = opt;
        options[i].value = opt;
    }            
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        dropdowns[i].appendChild(options[i]);
     }
 }
```

---

---

Edit 2:

I ran into a problem when taking a step back.
It stems from using the array of options in a loop. I knew each option element could only exist in a select once, but didn't follow that logic when writing the loop. The same option element (options[i]) is being changed and reused in each iteration, which wont work, you only get the last iteration's results. I believe this worked in the old code because it **redefined the element** in each iteration, not just changed it's attributes

**Does this rule an array out for this use?**

Comment: First thing to note: `var options = [
el1 = document.createElement("option"),` is probably not doing what you think it is. If you want an associative array aka object or hash: `var options = { el1: document.createElement("options"), …`

Comment: Is valid syntax I think he's just creating bunch of globals.

Comment: I would also kill the repeated code when you specify the arrays.  For example, `for( var i=1; i<=8; i++ ) dropdowns.push( document.getElementById( 'county' + i ) );`

Comment: And yet it seems like the user was able to execute it correctly. As he says **My original code was thrown together quickly but worked fine:**

Comment: I was thinking I needed to declare them first then add them to the array. Is that right?

Comment: i would guess your infinite loop is about the while `for(i=0;i<8;i++){  while (dropdowns[i].firstChild)`

Comment: I took the advice in jasonscript's answer, I wont need them individually by name. The code still keeps the page from rendering.

Comment: @JayHarris That is supposed to replace

    while (countyDrop1.firstChild) {
        countyDrop1.removeChild(countyDrop1.firstChild);
    };

8 times, which worked. It looks fine to me? Can I not refer to that node through an array?

Comment: @user2786343 im just guessing either that or the 3 for loops which equates to 8^3 iterations. man you just need to reevaluate and rewrite your code. I believe in you :) you can do it :)

Comment: @JayHarris That's whats so aggravating. Its more than 8^3, FLCounties is like 50 entries long. It iterates through the counties in the old and new code. The new code should SAVE work, because it doesn't redefine 8 el vars in each iteration, just assigns new values. Could objects be more efficient than arrays here?

Comment: @JayHarris Im taking your advice and reorganizing the code. I started with the old code and Im optimizing and testing it one step at a time. First, I separated the update step from the switch and made it a new function the switch calls. I also changed the clearing old counties into an array. Now Im moving other things into arrays, one at a time. Ill post the working code when its done.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you add elements to an array

```
var dropdowns = [
    countyDrop1 = document.getElementById("county1"),
    countyDrop2 = document.getElementById("county2"),
    countyDrop3 = document.getElementById("county3")
];
```

should be

```
var dropdowns = [
    document.getElementById("county1"),
    document.getElementById("county2"),
    document.getElementById("county3")
];
```

which you would then access like so

```
dropdown[0] // gives county1
```

you may want to use an object instead (note the difference `[]` becomes `{}`)

```
var dropdowns = {
    'county1':document.getElementById("county1"),
    'county2':document.getElementById("county2"),
    'county3':document.getElementById("county3")
};
```

which you can then access like so

```
dropdown.county1
```

Comment: And thats not how you answer a question in SO :p

Comment: can you not define them in the array's define?

Comment: @thefourtheye accidental hit of the add comment button. See updated answer

Comment: I took out the variable names, as I wont need them. The script still holds the page from rendering.

Comment: Is there an advantage to objects here? besides being able to refer to the variables in the object by name that is.

Comment: @user2786343 I don't think there's any advantage really. I wasn't sure what kind of behavior you were expecting since in your array declarations you were writing `countyDrop1 = ....`

Comment: Just a convention I brought from the old code. I rarely use javascript arrays anymore and thought they needed names.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in the comments above, when adding the options to the select, I cannot use an array. II ended up using a two dimensional array for the counties, and a second array for the state codes that my php script submits to the form.

I realize that the arrays would be better defined as objects, but the deadline for the project is up and this code is efficient enough for production use. Here is a condensed version of my final code (until things slow down and I find time to revisit the code):

```
ALCounties = ["Autauga","Baldwin","Barbour","Bibb",etc];
AKCounties = ["Anchorage Borough","Bethel Census Area",etc];
etc

stateCountyList = [ALCounties,AKCounties,etc];

stateCode = [ "AL","AK","AZ","AR",etc];

countyDrops = [
    document.getElementById("county1"),
    document.getElementById("county2"),
    document.getElementById("county3"),
    document.getElementById("county4"),
    document.getElementById("county5"),
    document.getElementById("county6"),
    document.getElementById("county7"),
    document.getElementById("county8")
];

defaultOpts = [
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option"),
    document.createElement("option")
];

//If a user loads the page with a state previously stored in the db
var initialState = document.getElementById("state").value;
getState(initialState);

// Replaces the switch in the old code.
// Passed value of option in state select on the page, matches it to a var in stateCode, calls updateState to create a list for that state
function getState(sel) {
    clearSetFirst(" - Select a state above first. - ");
    if (sel != ""){
        var valid = false;
        for (i=0;i<stateCode.length;i++){
            if(sel == stateCode[i]){
                updateState(stateCountyList[i]);
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!valid){
            clearSetFirst(" - Not available for this state. - ")
        }
    }
}

//Creates the list 
function updateState(state){
    clearSetFirst("- Select a County -");
    for(var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        var opt = state[i];
        //These CANNOT be a reused array, options must be unique, so they are redecalred each iteration.
        var el1 = document.createElement("option");
        el1.textContent = opt;
        el1.value = opt;
        var el2 = document.createElement("option");
        el2.textContent = opt;
        el2.value = opt;
        var el3 = document.createElement("option");
        el3.textContent = opt;
        el3.value = opt;
        var el4 = document.createElement("option");
        el4.textContent = opt;
        el4.value = opt;
        var el5 = document.createElement("option");
        el5.textContent = opt;
        el5.value = opt;
        var el6 = document.createElement("option");
        el6.textContent = opt;
        el6.value = opt;
        var el7 = document.createElement("option");
        el7.textContent = opt;
        el7.value = opt;
        var el8 = document.createElement("option");
        el8.textContent = opt;
        el8.value = opt;
        //I thought about 
        countyDrops[0].appendChild(el1);
        countyDrops[1].appendChild(el2);
        countyDrops[2].appendChild(el3);
        countyDrops[3].appendChild(el4);
        countyDrops[4].appendChild(el5);
        countyDrops[5].appendChild(el6);
        countyDrops[6].appendChild(el7);
        countyDrops[7].appendChild(el8);
    }
}

// Clears the list if no value is selected and sets the first options text to msg 
function clearSetFirst(msg){
    for (var i=0;i<8;i++){
        if (countyDrops[i].value == "") {
            while (countyDrops[i].firstChild) {
                countyDrops[i].removeChild(countyDrops[i].firstChild);
            }
            defaultOpts[i].textContent = msg;
            defaultOpts[i].value = "";
            countyDrops[i].appendChild(defaultOpts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your support. I am definitely open to suggestions for further optimizations, as the code is still 31 KB due to the size of the arrays.